# How did Dumbledore know about Frank Bryce's death?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Chapter 23 of *Half-Blood Prince*, quoted below, suggests that Dumbledore knew that Frank Bryce had been killed by Voldemort. I can't recall ever seeing him obtain this information, so when did it happen? Did I miss a paragraph somewhere?

> *After an interval of some years [from Voldemort's first death], however, he used Nagini to kill an old Muggle man, and it might then have occurred to him to turn her into his last Horcrux*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### He read it in the Muggle newspapers

> Dumbledore sighed again, and he looked older, and wearier, than ever.
>
> ‘The years of Voldemort’s ascent to power,’ he said, ‘were marked with disappearances. Bertha Jorkins has vanished without trace in the place where Voldemort was certainly known to be last. Mr Crouch, too, has disappeared … within these very grounds. **And there was a third disappearance, one which the Ministry, I regret to say, does not consider of any importance, for it concerns a Muggle. His name was Frank Bryce, he lived in the village where Voldemort’s father grew up, and he has not been seen since last August. You see, I read the Muggle newspapers, unlike most of my Ministry friends.’**
>
> Dumbledore looked very seriously at Harry. ‘These disappearances seem to me to be linked. The Ministry disagrees – as you may have heard, while waiting outside my office.’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Chapter 30 - The Pensieve</sub>

Comment: I'm more than happy to accept this answer, but I can't help but notice that it raises another question: How on Earth did he learn that Voldemort used Nagini to kill him?

Comment: While this does provide an explanation, there are more than 500.000 deaths per year in UK, and it's unlikely that all of them are reported, or that Dumbledore has the time to read about all of them

Comment: @RalfFriedl There is a difference between death and disappearance. The latter are much more rare and more likely to be reported, especially in a local newspaper. If Dumbledore was keeping tabs on the places relevant to Voldemort, it would make perfect sense to read local news.